# Onpress color change

Tags: react-native

I'm creating application which changes text color on button press and having trouble doing that, i'm new to react native need some help.

```
var TextColor = 'black';

<View style={styles.Button}>
            <Button
            onPress={ () => {
                this.TextColor = 'green',
                alert('greeen')

            }}
            title="Button1"
            color="green"
            />

        </View>
<Text style={styles.Text}>Text1

        </Text>
const styles = StyleSheet.create({

Text: {
    width: 150,
    height: 50,
    margin: 10,
    fontSize: 20,
    color: TextColor
},


});
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a state to trigger a re-render on the component, you cannot change the color by just updating the `TextColor` variable.

To do it you need to put that variable in your state:

```
constructor(props){
    super(props)
    this.state={
        textColor="black"
    }
}
```

Then, on button press, you just change the variable color by doing:

```
onPress={ ()=> this.setState({ textColor="Green" }) }
```

As last thing, you need to merge the styles you already have with the color you give:

```
<Text style={[ styles.Text, { color:this.state.textColor } ]}>Text1</Text>
```

Don't forget to remove the color from the `StyleSheet`:

```
Text: {
    width: 150,
    height: 50,
    margin: 10,
    fontSize: 20,
    color: "black"      //If you want to keep it don't use TextColor variable
},
```

Comment: Ask whatever you want about it ^^

Comment: Can we initiate State outside constructor?

Like:

this.state={
        textColor="black"
    }

Comment: Yes, you can write, inside your react component, `state={textColor: "black"}`

Answer (score 0):

first creat state

```
// cars lisst btns selected Highlight.
    const [btnSelecteBg, setbtnSelecteBg] = useState()
```

then creat function

```
 const carSelectHandle = (e) => {

      
        // selected car HighLight #fff .
        setbtnSelecteBg(e)
    }
```

then create an element with on press method and style Dynamic with if else condition replacer.

```
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => carSelectHandle(0)} style={[styles.list_btns, { backgroundColor: btnSelecteBg == 0 ? "#fff" : "#113c74" }]}><Text style={styles.txt_list_btns}>{cars[0].name}</Text></TouchableOpacity>
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => carSelectHandle(1)} style={[styles.list_btns, { backgroundColor: btnSelecteBg == 1 ? "#fff" : "#113c74" }]}><Text style={styles.txt_list_btns}>{cars[1].name}</Text></TouchableOpacity>
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => carSelectHandle(2)} style={[styles.list_btns, { backgroundColor: btnSelecteBg == 2 ? "#fff" : "#113c74" }]}><Text style={styles.txt_list_btns}>{cars[2].name}</Text></TouchableOpacity>
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => carSelectHandle(3)} style={[styles.list_btns, { backgroundColor: btnSelecteBg == 3 ? "#fff" : "#113c74" }]}><Text style={styles.txt_list_btns}>{cars[3].name}</Text></TouchableOpacity>
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => carSelectHandle(4)} style={[styles.list_btns, { backgroundColor: btnSelecteBg == 4 ? "#fff" : "#113c74" }]}><Text style={styles.txt_list_btns}>{cars[4].name}</Text></TouchableOpacity>
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => carSelectHandle(5)} style={[styles.list_btns, { backgroundColor: btnSelecteBg == 5 ? "#fff" : "#113c74" }]}><Text style={styles.txt_list_btns}>{cars[5].name}</Text></TouchableOpacity>
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => carSelectHandle(6)} style={[styles.list_btns, { backgroundColor: btnSelecteBg == 6 ? "#fff" : "#113c74" }]}><Text style={styles.txt_list_btns}>{cars[6].name}</Text></TouchableOpacity>
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => carSelectHandle(7)} style={[styles.list_btns, { backgroundColor: btnSelecteBg == 7 ? "#fff" : "#113c74" }]}><Text style={styles.txt_list_btns}>{cars[7].name}</Text></TouchableOpacity>
```